# perl: can't find module but its in the @INC paths?

Tags: perl, perlbrew

In this particular case I'm trying to access IPC::Open3:

```
bash-4.2# perl RunScript hier_clustering1.py
Can't locate IPC/open3.pm in @INC (you may need to install the IPC::open3 module) (@INC contains: /root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/lib/site_perl/5.20.0/x86_64-linux /root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/lib/site_perl/5.20.0 /root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/lib/5.20.0/x86_64-linux /root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/lib/5.20.0 .) at RunScript line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at RunScript line 4.
bash-4.2# cd /root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/lib/5.20.0
bash-4.2# cd IPC
bash-4.2# ls
Cmd.pm  Open2.pm  Open3.pm
```

As you can see IPC::Open3 is clearly installed and in the path.

this is within a perlbrew shell running the perlbrew-installed perl:

```
bash-4.2# which perl
/root/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.0/bin/perl
```

whats going on here???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your capitalization. `open3` and `Open3` are different.